# Special price showing proper in product list page but not showing in product view.phtml in magento 1.8.1?

Tags: php, magento-1.8

Special price showing proper in product list page but not showing in product view.phtml in magento 1.8.1?
view.phtml ->http://pastebin.com/TsydMEJ6

Comment: are you using any custom theme/? Or default magento theme??

Comment: if you are using any custom theme? Than compare your view.phtml file with default theme file.. there should be some code for special prize..

Answer (score 0):

Go to Promotions > Catalog Price Rule > YOUR RULE > Actions > Enable Discount to Subproducts > YES >set the discount exactly the same as you did above it.